# Flatten out a Record field

Tags: google-bigquery

Assume we have a BigQuery table like the following:

[image]

Where "Col1" is a Record field. What would be the most efficient way to "flatten out" the table so that part of the Record field becomes columns:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below option

```
select * from (
  select key, name, value
  from your_table, unnest(col1)
)
pivot (any_value(value) for name in ('A','B','C','D'))
```

if applied to sample data as in your question

[image]

the output is

[image]